# How to graph two matrices using the command imagesc?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I need to help to graph two variables (two matrices) by using the command imagesc. The matrices have the same size but I do not know how to write appropriately the code to get right result.

In my problem, the x - axe is the longitude on the ground, y - axe is the vertical position -depth (Df)- for which is computing T, it means T(Df). The general idea is get a temperature profile.

```
clear all
x=1:1:10;

a=-0.5; b=0.5;
topo = a + (b-a).*rand(1,10);

df=-5:1:20;

for i=1:length(x);

d1=-5:1:topo(i);d1=d1';
d2=topo(i):1:20;d2=d2';
df=unique(vertcat(d1,d2));
d=df+topo(i); 

z=find(d<0);
T1(z)= NaN;

z=find(d>=0 & d<=20); 
T1(z)= 0.3*d(z).^2;

%save into a matrix
    Ti(:,i)=T1;
Di(:,i)=df';
end

hh=imagesc(x,df,Ti);colormap('jet'),set(hh,'AlphaData',~isnan(Ti)); 
set(gca,'YDir','reverse');hold on;
plot(x,topo,'k');grid on;
```

I have tried two things:

1st.

```
Ti(:, i) = T1;
Df(:, i) = df';

Cx{i} = T1; 
Cy{i} = df;
Tf    = [Cx; Cy];

hh = imagesc (x, Tf{:});
```

An this error appears: Error in imagesc (line 39)
    hh = image(varargin{:},'CDataMapping','scaled');

2nd.

```
hh = imagesc (x, Df(:), T1(:));
```

None have worked. Because I need that each column of Ti is plotted against the correspondent valur of Df.

This looks like easy but I have could solve it. If someone could help me with this I will appreciate a lot.

Thanks in advance!

[Print screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sTQ0.png)

Comment: what is the line `size(Df) = size(Ti)` supposed to do?

Comment: I'm very confused what you're trying to do. `image` and its sister function `imagesc` are used to represent a matrix as an image. You seem to want to plot a graph instead (i.e. one variable as a function of another). Is that right?

Comment: perhaps you intend to `plot (Df(:), T1(:))` ?

Comment: Hi Tasos Papastylianou! Yes, I have the plot (Df(:), T1(:)). But, I need to represent each line (51 lines) of this plot using imagesc because Df and T1 are matrices.

Comment: What I need that T1(:,1) be graphed with the corresponding values of Df(:,1) which is different for the next column (i). Something like hh=imagesc(x,Df(:),T1(:)). size(Df) = size(Ti) was only to show that info.

Comment: I have added a print screen to try visualize my problem better. I hope it may useful. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, this still makes no sense. What are the labels on those axes? Are you 'plotting' each column of a ***matrix*** T1 against a ***vector*** Df? If that's the case you just need to visualise the matrix T1 as an image: `imagesc(T1)`. Otherwise, if Df is a ***matrix***, then how do you expect to plot T1 as a function of Df? Perhaps T1 and Df are supposed to form a grid (i.e. they specify coordinates in the x-y plane) such that at each point in the grid you have an associated scalar value? (in which case, what you need is a `surface` or `surf` plot)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. something I can copy and run on my computer). I can't do this here since `df`, `out` and `T` are undefined (and there are errors in the code).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Matlab help for imagesc:
imagesc(x,y,C) -or- imagesc('XData',x,'YData',y,'CData',C)

x - 1 x N vector for horizontal coordinates

y - 1 x M vector for vertical coordinates

C - N x M matrix with intensities for each point [x(i), y(j)]